# CUDA. Example to show how performance depends on the number of threads

Tags: cuda

I assume, the number of threads/blocks, that can be run in parallel, is limited. I mean, if I have too much threads/blocks, some of them will be executed sequentially on some processing units. I need to build the next example. Let's say, I have some `kernel<<<B, N>>>()`. The execution time of `kernel<<<1,1>>>()` equals t0.

The first task is to find maximum values for B and N, that the execution time of `kernel<<<B, N>>>()` t ~ t0. And then I want to have the execution time of `kernel<<<B, 2*N>>>()` (or `kernel<<<2*B, N>>>()`) t1 ~ 2*t.

I have Tesla C2075 with 448 CUDA cores (14 SMs) and hope to build an example with occupancy 1.

Is this possible and if yes, how should the kernel function look like, may be some example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CUDA the threads are scheduled on individual SM's as warps. Each warp can contain at max 32 threads.The scheduler will try to execute the warps in parallel fashion inside the SM's.If the data for a particular warp is not ready,it is held by the scheduler until it is available.Now as far as your questions is concerned, I believe it is possible to do what you are trying to achieve using `cudaEvent_t` (for measuring the execution time of a kernel).

The launch configuration that is `kernel<<<B,Tnum>>>(arg1...argn);` totally depends upon how much parallelism can you exploit in your algorithm. Also,the number of threads is something you must decide based on the best execution time that you get by launching the kernel.

In many cases,launching multiple blocks with `128/256` threads suffices just to achieve optimal speed up. To give an example,lets say we want to add individual elements of two arrays of size `1024` into third array, the kernel function with 1 block would look something like

```
__global__ void kadd(int *c,int *a,int *b)
{
  unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;//Since only one block of 1024 threads suffices
  if(tid < MAXNUM)  //MAXNUM = 1024
    c[tid] = a[tid]+ b[tid];
}
```

And the launch config would be

```
kadd<<<1,1024>>>(c,a,b);
```

This however, will only execute a block on one of the SM's of your GPU,which means you are not utilizing the GPU resources fully. To get more from your GPU, what you can do is you can
use multiple blocks and threads.The kernel will look something like

```
__global__ void kadd(int *c,int *a,int *b)
{
  unsigned int tid = blockIDx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;//Since multiple blocks are used
  if(tid < MAXNUM)  //MAXNUM = 1024
    c[tid] = a[tid]+ b[tid];
}
```

and the corresponding launch configuration would be

```
kadd<<<8,128>>>(c,a,b);
```

This will launch `8` blocks of `128` threads each.You can play around with this launch configurations based on your algorithm requirements. You can further explore these launch configurations by launching `2D` or `3D` grids to get the most out of your GPU.

As such, timing the kernel would give you the configuration that suits best for your requirements. This will also change depending on use of shared memory,coalesced access of global memory and other factors.
In the end, I would like to mention that there is an occupancy calculator made available by NVIDIA which you can use to find the best combination on blocks and threads,for achieving higher occupancy.

Comment: Worth pointing out that a memory bandwidth limited kernel, such as the one provided in this answer, is not ideal for scalability analysis in a GPU. A compute bound kernel will be easier to understand.

Comment: @talonmies...can you throw more light on memory bandwidth limited kernels vs. compute bound kernels?

Comment: @abhinole NVIDIA has some [webinars](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/gpu-computing-webinars) which you may find interesting to learn more about mem bandwidth limited vs. compute bound.  In particular "CUDA Optimization: Identifying Performance Limiters by Dr Paulius Micikevicius
" is a good one.  After that, instruction limited kernels with Gernot Ziegler and memory bandwidth limited kernels with Tim Schroeder might be interesting.